# Server crashes when the client is closing

Tags: python, sockets, networking, client-server

I have encountered this problem earlier today. This is my first network application.

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()

# Reserve a port for your service.
port = 12345
# Bind to the port
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

# Now wait for client connection.
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
try:
    while True:
        # connection, address
        content = conn.recv(1024)
        if content in ('status', 'stop', 'start', 'reload', 'restart'):
            conn.send('%s received' % content)
        else:
            conn.send('Invalid command')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    conn.close()
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345

s.connect((host, port))
try:
    while True:
        print ''
        value = raw_input('Enter a command:\n')
        if value != '':
            s.send(value)
            print s.recv(1024)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()
```

It is a very basic client/server application. The server starts up, and wait for
the client to send commands. The client connects to the server, asks the user to
type a command. Commands are then sent to the server which replies `<command>
received` or `Invalid command`.
The code was running fine, until I hit `CTRL`+`C`. The server crashed. Why is that ?

Example:

```
python client.py 

Enter a command:
stop
stop received

Enter a command:
status
status received

Enter a command:
bla
Invalid command

Enter a command:
^C
```

On the server side:

```
python server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 25, in <module>
    conn.send('Invalid command')
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Did you know that `socket.send` is not guaranteed to send the entire string you pass to it?

Comment: Since I am reading only 1024 bytes? If so, yes I know, but I am only reading a few characters, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't care if your application is reliable. :)  Many routers can and will fragment 1024 bytes (or less) of TCP traffic into multiple IP datagrams.  Plus there's the other bug, which is that your protocol has no framing: nothing stops your server from accidentally getting "statusstop" as the result of a single read.  You might want to read http://www.xml.com/pub/au/215 to learn more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `accept` in a while loop, too.  Something like:

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()        # accept one connection.
    while True:                    # Receive until client closes.
        content = conn.recv(1024)  # waits to receive something.
        if not content:            # Receive nothing? client closed connection,
            break                  #   so exit loop to close connection.
        if content in ('status', 'stop', 'start', 'reload', 'restart'):
            conn.send('%s received' % content)
        else:
            conn.send('Invalid command')
    conn.close()                   # close the connection
```

Also note `recv` returns empty string when the client closes the connection, hence the `if not content: break`.

Comment: Why is that better than a `try/except` statement? Can you be more specific? Otherwise, thanks for the answer

Comment: Smoother code flow.  Non-repetitive (accepting in two places).  Clearer intent.  Make a connection, receive data until client closes, close connection and repeat.

Comment: The part I didn't get was: if content is '', then it means the client shut the connection. Thanks

Comment: Read the `socket.recv` documentation.  For a synchronous connection, `recv` will wait until at least one byte of data is ready, but will return zero bytes (an empty string) if the client closes the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I wasn't recreating a new connection on my server for new future clients, and then, when it was hitting the line `conn.send('Invalid command')`, it was crashing. To solve this:

I just replaced:

```
conn.send('Invalid command')
```

with:

```
try:
    conn.send('Invalid command')
except socket.error:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
```